# Call dispatch function for Redux from string variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux

I have a component that gets reused for various reasons. From the component I am updating different parts of the store based on the url parameter. I am having an issue trying to call the dispatch function based on a passed string. Here is my import:

```
import {updateUnassignedListingLeads, updateAssignedListingLeads} from "../../actions";
```

And then my code to call the dispatch. If I put the updateAssignedListingLeads where storeName is it works. I have also checked that the url is correct coming in. It says it is not a function.

```
reloadFilteredListingLeads = () =>{

let curr = this
var url = this.removeParameter()
const parsed = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
let column = parsed.column
let order = parsed.order
let term = parsed.term
let filters = parsed.filters
let group = parsed.group


const vals = {
  column: column,
  order: order,
  filters: filters,
  term: term
};

let strip = url.replace("/", "");
const storeName = eval('update' + group.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + group.slice(1));

axios.post('/filtered-' + strip, vals, headers).then(response => {
  curr.props.dispatch(storeName(response.data))
});
}
```

This is the bottom of the file. I know it works without trying to use a string variable as the dispatch action. If I replace storeName with updateAssignedListingLeads then it works.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return {
    app: state.app,
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(ListingCoordinatorDetail));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you using storeName function and it return value in different places in your application ????

Comment: no I just want to use it as a dynamic use in the dispatch function

Answer (score 0):

are you using connect API in your application to connect redux state with react?

Comment: Yes, like I said, if I change the variable name to the actual function name it works.

Comment: the component is 1600 lines. I will edit to show entire function and map state to props

Comment: where this curr variable coming from?

Comment: var curr = this. it helps keep scope of this inside axios callback

Comment: let curr = this can you please check wether u r getting componant reference in this or it simply referring to current function only

Comment: curr is component ref

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had to import it differently and add it to the eval like this:

```
import * as Update from '../../actions';

const storeName = eval(Update['update' + group.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + group.slice(1)]);
```

Comment: Using `eval()` is a terrible idea: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!